# Get member name from expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am having expression

```
{e => Convert(e.sal1)}
```

i want to get the sal1 from it. Not the value of sal1.

if i convert the expression in member expression it gives me null.

Comment: Guys any other solution than this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have a MemberExpression (the sal1 property), wrapped in a UnaryExpression (the convert call), wrapped in a LambdaExpression (the 'e => ...')
The one-liner to get the "sal1" is:

```
((MemberExpression)
  ((UnaryExpression)
    ((LambdaExpression)exp).Body).Operand).Member.Name
```

If you want to write this a bit more flexible, then you can go for an ExpressionVisitor:

```
string lastMemberName = new MyVisitor().GetLastVisitedMember(exp);

class MyVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private string memberName = "";

    public string GetLastVisitedMember(Expression exp)
    {
        Visit(exp);
        return memberName;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        memberName = node.Member.Name;
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```